# how come ruby's single os thread doesn't block while copying a file?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, io

My assumptions:

- MRI ruby 1.8.X doesn't have native threads but green threads.
- The OS is not aware of these green threads.
- issuing an IO-heavy operation should suspend the whole process until the proper IO interruption is issued back.

With these I've created a [simple ruby program](https://gist.github.com/4686889) that does the following:

- starts a thread that prints "working!" every second.
- issues an IO request to copy a large (1gb) file on the "main" thread.

Now one would guess that being the green threads invisible to the OS, it would put the whole process on the "blocked" queue and the "working!" green thread would not execute. Surprisingly, it works :S

Does anyone know what's going on there? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know ruby, but javascript is single threaded and has non-blocking IO, when using serverside javascript (eg. node.js) issuing fs.readFile does not block execution but rather accepts a callback parameter, when the read is done the callback function is called.

Comment: If a thread is known to be blocking on an I/O operation then couldn't the Ruby interpreter simply schedule another thread in the meantime?

Comment: @maerics it's not up to ruby, requesting an I/O must be done through the OS and when the OS notices some process needs to be blocked waiting for I/O it will suspend it.

Comment: @maerics is right. the blocked thread will sleep while it waits for a response and the interpreter will schedule another thread in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When MRI 1.9 initiates, it spawns two native threads. One thread is for the VM, the other is used to handle signals. Rubinis uses this strategy, as does the JVM. Pipes can be used to communicate any info from other processes.

As for the `FileUtils` module, the `cd`, `pwd`, `mkdir`, `rm`, `ln`, `cp`, `mv`, `chmod`, `chown`, and `touch` methods are all, to some degree, outsourced to OS native utilities using the internal API of the `StreamUtils` submodule while the second thread is left to wait for a signal from the an outside process. Since these methods are quite thread-safe, there is no need to lock the interpreter and thus the methods don't block eachother.

Edit:

> MRI 1.8.7 is quite smart, and knows that when a Thread is waiting for some external event (such as a browser to send an HTTP request), the Thread can be put to sleep and be woken up when data is detected. -  Evan Phoenix from Engine Yard in [Ruby, Concurrency, and You](https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/ruby-concurrency-and-you)

The implementation basic implementation for FileUtils has not changed much sense 1.8.7 from looking at the source. 1.8.7 also uses a sleepy timer thread to wait for a IO response. The main difference in 1.9 is the use of native threads rather than green threads. Also the thread [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread_pthread.c#L1344-L1395) is much more refined.

By thread-safe I mean that since there is nothing shared between the processes, there is no reason to lock the global interpreter. There is a misconception that Ruby "blocks" when doing certain tasks. Whenever a thread has to block, i.e. wait without using any cpu, Ruby simply schedules another thread. However in certain situations, like a rack-server using 20% of the CPU waiting for a response, it can be appropriate to unlock the interpreter and allow concurrent threads to handle other requests during the wait. These threads are, in a sense, working in parallel. The GIL is unlocked with the `rb_thread_blocking_region` API. Here is a good post on this [subject](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/7/5/whos-afraid-of-the-big-bad-lock/).

Comment: I'm talking specifically about MRI 1.8.x as the first point states, since 1.9.x has native threads and this question wouldn't make sense on that platform. Can you please point to the sources that show that the IO in ruby is indeed nonblocking? and what do you mean about "no need for the GIL"? is it something you can remove for some parts of your code?

Comment: I have made an edit to better answer your questions. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any point that might still be vague.

Answer (score 4):

There is no atomic kernel file copy operation. It's a lot of fairly short reads and writes that are entering and exiting the kernel.

As a result, the process is constantly getting control back. Signals are delivered.

Green threads work by hooking the Ruby-level thread dispatcher into low-level I/O and signal reception. As long as these hooks catch control periodically the green threads will act quite a bit like more concurrent threads would.

Unix originally had a quite thread-unaware but beautifully simple abstract machine model for the user process environment.

As the years went by support for concurrency in general and threads in particular were added bit-by-bit in two different ways.

1. Lots of little kludges were added to check if I/O would block, to fail (with later retry) if I/O would block, to interrupt slow tty I/O for signals but then transparently return to it, etc. When the Unix API's were merged each kludge existed in more than one form. *Lots of choices.*<sup>1.</sup>
2. Direct support for threads in the form of multiple kernel-visible processes sharing an address space was also added. These [threads are dangerous and untestable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf&ei=pkALUY62IeOsigKfzIDACg&usg=AFQjCNFKbD8gsVjP71jOd1-cFbUiGK96Cw&bvm=bv.41867550,d.cGE) but widely supported and used. Mostly, programs don't crash. As time goes on, latent bugs become visible as the hardware supports more true concurrency. I'm not the least bit worried that Ruby doesn't fully support [that nightmare.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading)

---

<sup>1. The good thing about standards is that there are so many of them.</sup>