# Ruby - how do I wait for a file to finish moving before the next action?

Tags: ruby, windows

I have a script that is reading excel spreadsheets. Each file gets copied to a new location before it gets opened ensuring that no one else is inside the file at the same time. The weird thing is that sometimes my script breaks because the file cant be found in its new location yet.

```
# copy the file to a new destination
# the file is originating on a windows file server, 
# the destination is my local downloads folder on a windows machine.  
FileUtils.cp(some_filepath, destination_path)
# the next line gives an error, because the file doesnt exist at its location yet
Spreadsheet.open(file_at_new_destination)
```

I have tried doing an `until` block, doing a checkup to see if the file exists before the script continues, but even that doesnt work and just runs forever.

```
# check if file exists
until File.exist?(file_at_new_destination) do
  print '.'
end
```

How can I ensure that the script doesnt keep running intil the file is done moving?

here is my error that shows up in my rake task

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
C:\Users\ALilland\Downloads\tmp_dest\102035 Western Digital Job Status Reports.xls
```

Comment: I think the naming convention is what making issue here. Can you check on the console File.exist?(path)? To see whether we need escape some special chars like space or : or back-slash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635942/how-come-rubys-single-os-thread-doesnt-block-while-copying-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is single threaded, you don't have to wait for file to get copied to destination path.

Use **cp_r** instead **cp** when copying a directory with all subdirectories.

```
# copy directory to destination directory recursively.    
FileUtils.cp_r(some_filepath, destination_path)
if File.exist?(file_at_new_destination)
 Spreadsheet.open(file_at_new_destination)
end
```